# Accurate Timer Class

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I need a Timer for a website I'm making. There are Timer's that I've used before, (only, in Windows Forms and WPF apps) - not in Web Development. So I'm not quite sure about which Timer would be the most appropriate, and most accurate one to use in a Web page.

I have a few requirements, which are:

1. It must be as accurate as possible
2. It needs to be a Timer based on a Time period, I.e: 2:00:00

Kind of like how those timers work on bidding sites.

I'm not looking for any samples (although that would be appreciated if you've got some laying around somewhere) - I'm just not sure where to look, or what one would be the best one for the job.

Comment: The timer class you use doesn't really have anything to do with javascript or AJAX if you're looking for a C# class.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with `DateTime.UtcNow`?  It sounds like it is just for a website.  Client's latency to the server means you probably won't need to keep time much more accurate than some large-ish fraction of a second.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485839/high-performance-timer-vs-stopwatch

Answer (score 2):

If by web development you mean JavaScript you can get the current time in milliseconds using the Date object.

The level of accuracy depends on the browser and/or device.

Here is an example of using it for profiling:

```
var startTime = new Date().getTime();
// some long running operation
var endTime = new Date().getTime();
var ellapsedMilliseconds = endTime - startTime;
```

Answer (score 1):

> Kind of like how those timers work on bidding sites.

A timer like that would use roughly accurate JavaScript client side script to generate a clock, but the results would need to be validated server-side to be trustworthy (for example, you don't want me sending you an HTTP request saying that I really *was* the last bidder on an eBay item without checking it against something I can't spoof).

A simple timer could just rely on `setTimeout()` or `setInterval()`. They aren't truly exact by any means but they will fire at approximate times that are close enough for most uses.

To perform an reasonably accurate client-side countdown that updates a client-side clock:

- Set a starting date variable
- Check the current date every 100ms using `setInterval()`
- Compare the different and see if some time period has elapsed
- Perform some action when the time period has elapsed (and make sure to call `clearInterval()`)

Again, you **must** validate your timer results server-side if you want them to be tamper-resistant. You might asynchronously communicate with the server very regularly, or just when a countdown is reached.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer @Tim M, you've certainly given me a bit to think about and more than enough to get me started. Thanks again!